# Compress a folder and exclude sub-directories in terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, compression, tar

I'm trying to compress a folder using the command below and exclude multiple sub-folders as it has over 10GBs which i don't need:

```
    ubuntu@ip-172-31-X-XXX:/var/www$ tar -zcvf master16march.tar.gz master -x "master/media/com_easysocial/photos/*" "master/media/com_easysocial/avatars/*" "master/media/com_easysocial/tmp/*" "master/media/com_easydiscuss/attachments/*" "master/images/joomcareer/*"
```

And i got this error:

```
    tar: You may not specify more than one `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label' option
    Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `--exclude` (not `-x`) and repeat this long option before every pattern, like:

```
tar -zcvf master16march.tar.gz master --exclude "master/media/com_easysocial/photos/*" --exclude "master/media/com_easysocial/avatars/*" --exclude "master/media/com_easysocial/tmp/*" --exclude "master/media/com_easydiscuss/attachments/*" --exclude "master/images/joomcareer/*"
```

Alternatively you can use `-X` to point to a file containing exclude patterns.

If you want to exclude folders entirely (not only files), use folder path without wildcards, like:

```
tar -zcvf master16march.tar.gz master --exclude "master/media/com_easysocial/photos" --exclude "master/media/com_easysocial/avatars" --exclude "master/media/com_easysocial/tmp" --exclude "master/media/com_easydiscuss/attachments" --exclude "master/images/joomcareer"
```

Comment: I did this too but it still compressed the sub-folders inside of photos, avatars, tmp, attachments and joomcareer. The asterisks doesn't seem to be working.